# Google Pay UPI integration using URL Schemes - iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-pay

I'm developing an app that accepts Payment using UPI, as per the guidelines provided by the NPCI documentation available at link **https://www.npci.org.in/sites/all/themes/npcl/images/PDF/UPI_Linking_Specs_ver_1.5.1.pdf** I am able to replicate the Intent base behavior in android as per the documentation of Google Pay available at link **https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments** but I am not able to achieve the same behavior in iOS using URL schemes if more than one UPI supported apps are installed in iPhone.

e.g. If I am using below code in iPhone if only Google Pay is installed then the below code is working fine

```
let urlString = "upi://pay?pa=test@dcb&cu=INR&mc=0000&appName=TEST&tn=To&am=1.0&pn=TEST&tr=TEST-1574159602900"

guard let url = URL.init(string: textView.text) else {
            return
        }
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

Anyone can help me to find out the exact URL schemes supported by Google Pay to initiate the payment using URL schemes if more than one Apps are installed that support **UPI** URL scheme **i.e. upi://**

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the prefix for the `UPI PSP` in the `deeplink` before invoking in case of `iOS`.

> e.x.
> tez://upi/pay?pa=exeex.payu@indus&pn=exexe%20E-Retail%20Private%20Limited&tr=11426866303&tid=NYK-176044-6770938&am=7.00&cu=INR&tn=UPI%20Transaction%20for%20NYK-176044-6770938

Comment: The prefix tez works perfecrtly, do you know the prefix for other apps, or some reference doc where i can look for these prefix

I need prefix for phonepe, amazon pay etc

Comment: After payment success / failed, how you are handling the response or where can we get the response?

Comment: @Harsha : you should receive the S2S response/EVENT(server to server response) from your Payment Gateway(RazorPay,JusPay etc.). Based on SUCCESS/FAILED/PENDING update your Payment Status.                                               In Android APPS , upon payment completion, the UPI app returns the result back to your activity in onActivityResult method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use application native web view instead of opening browser(outside of the application) 
Seel the [create payment request](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/create-payment-method) using web.

> supportedMethods: "https://tez.google.com/pay"

Comment: can you please provide sample code or class file in detail to implement. it would be much helpful.

Comment: Can we do this without backend, I mean independently in mobile app?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/web-payments-deep-dive-soham-bhattacharjee/) there are big differences between Google Pay in India and rest of the world, so if you want to handle requests from India and rest of the world without Google Pay installed (or if there are other problems with opening upi URL scheme) you need to determine from where payment is initiated. 
For India solution from AtulParmar should work, and for other places try to use guide from article mentioned above. Native web view may, but not necessarily will help.
Good luck!