# How to integrate Google Pay in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, payment, google-pay, upi

Hi Friends i have searched about google pay integration in iOS swift. I didn't t find any relevant solution. please help me how to work on this, if any links or examples please provide link and guide me

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a question about initiating a Google Pay action in India? Example, with UPI?

If so, you can try launching it with the following [UPI URI scheme](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf):

> `upi://pay?parm-name=param-value&param-name=pram-value&...`

That should launch whatever app is configured to handle UPI.

If you want to launch the Google Pay app in India directly, you could try the following instead:

`gpay://upi/pay?parm-name=param-value&param-name=pram-value&...`

Comment: looking for google pay in india only.. can you give me brief description about implementing process or please provide if you have any sample file. thank you

Comment: I'm actually not an iOS developer so I can't provide any details. Section 1.2 in the UPI URI scheme should describe the parameters that you can supply.

Comment: @RohithSingh Did you find the solution

Comment: @RohithSingh is there anything u got for all UPI apps of schema files if yes please share it so i can implement as like this.

Comment: @DavenderVerma any chances u get schema file please share it

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBAction func action_proceedBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let paValue = "Client_upi_key"  //payee address upi id
    let pnValue = "Merchant Name"     // payee name
    let trValue = "1234ABCD"        //tansaction Id
    let urlValue = "http://url/of/the/order/in/your/website" //url for refernec
    let mcValue = "1234"  // retailer category code :- user id
    let tnValue = "Purchase in Merchant" //transction Note
    let amValue = "1"  //amount to pay
    let cuValue = "INR"    //currency
    
    let str =  "gpay://upi/pay?pa=\(paValue)&pn=\(pnValue)&tr=\(trValue)&mc=\(mcValue)&tn=\(tnValue)&am=\(amValue)&cu=\(cuValue)"
    
     guard let urlString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
     else {
         return
     }

     guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
         return
     }
    
     UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: How are you getting Google Pay's response after a successful transaction when user navigate back to the app?

Comment: @Suhail no i am looking a solution for that . Will check then will inform you. You can also comment if you found anything

Comment: Any update on this? How to get the payment response ?

Comment: @Muzammil. i don't . May Suhail help you

Comment: Thank you Davender... @Suhail Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: I did not! But there is a recent answer on one of the similar question. Check it out if it helps:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64496910/8485197

Comment: @Muzammil  Anyone find solution for this

Comment: @Suhail anything u got please share it

Comment: @DhavalBhadania I did not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Google Pay is only available for JavaScript v3 SDK and Android v2 SDK. Learn more here:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/client-side/ios/v4

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no way to integrate Google Pay in your iOS app. 
At least for native iOS app i suggest to use Apple Pay

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/implementation/)