# How to get Google Pay response after returning back to app in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, android-intent, google-pay

I'm trying to make a transaction through Google Pay app. I've implemented this so far:

```
let paValue = "Client_upi_key"  //payee address upi id
let pnValue = "Merchant Name"     // payee name
let trValue = "1234ABCD"        //tansaction Id
let urlValue = "http://url/of/the/order/in/your/website" //url for refernec
let mcValue = "1234"  // retailer category code :- user id
let tnValue = "Purchase in Merchant" //transction Note
let amValue = "1"  //amount to pay
let cuValue = "INR"    //currency

let str =  "gpay://upi/pay?pa=\(paValue)&pn=\(pnValue)&tr=\(trValue)&mc=\(mcValue)&tn=\(tnValue)&am=\(amValue)&cu=\(cuValue)"

 guard let urlString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
 else {
     return
 }

 guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
     return
 }

 UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Now I'm returning to my app & want to have some response like transactionID, userID etc from Google Pay. Is there any way like Android to use Intent in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the Google Pay API is only available on Android and Web. Judging from the [current docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api) only showing those options.

If you are looking for a simple payments API, [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic) I know is quite easy to implement. You could also try the [Apple Pay SDK](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/).

Comment: Is there any way that we can implement this in the web view & produce some response in the same?

Comment: @Suhail Have you find any solution for this? How to integrate GooglePay in iOS?

Comment: @Muzammil I did not! But there is a recent answer on one of the similar question. Check it out if it helps:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64496910/8485197