# How to make payment with iOS application with xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, implementation, google-pay

I am creating a demo project with xamarin and in that, I want to list down payment methods to pay. In that list, I want to add google pay. So that users can click on the google pay button and make payments using the google pay application. I want to know the implementation for iOS as I have found implementation for android. I have checked for the same but did not find anything fruitful. Can you please provide me the solution for that?

Comment: Why would you think that Google Pay would be an option on iOS? ApplePay is what you would use on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 I need to implement Google Pay as most of the people are using Google pay in India.

Answer (score 0):

`Google Pay` is only available on **Android** and **Web** .

However it seems there are some ways to implement Google Pay in India.

Refer to [official docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/ios/in-app-payments) , [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529370/how-to-integrate-google-pay-in-ios-swift) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083385/google-pay-upi-integration-using-url-schemes-ios/64496910#64496910) .

But We still recommend you to use [Apple Pay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/apple-pay), it is the best way .